# ASP.NET Core 2.0 - how to forward file from Azure Storage with auth

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-blob-storage, asp.net-core-2.0

I need an advice here first, then tech details.

My app generated PDF's and stores them in Azure Storage in a private container. But when user authenticates (I use Azure AD B2C) and goes to his personal page I need to show links to those PDF's. Now, those links must not be public, so I think I need:

1) some kind of middleware to auth the user when he accesses those kind of links

2) to request the file from Storage and pass it on to the response

What's the best way of doing this? (considering performance too)

My first idea was to use SAS tokens and just limit time for about 5-10 minutes. But what if user opens the page and leaves his browser open for an hour, then comes back and click on PDF link?

Comment: Using SAS tokens is the best choice for performance reasons. Instead of generating the blob URL on page load, just create a link to your API, inside the action generate the token and then return a Redirect response to the full path (uri + token) to azure storage. This way there is no possibility for the user obtain stale links to blobs.

Comment: Right. The only issue I may have here is when user gets the actual link to a PDF and sends via email. If token expires, the link is broken. If not, it's basically publicly available... So I thought maybe there's another way.

Comment: It's not clear what is your intended behavior, what you are introducing is a problem no matter what method you will use. Why should the user send a link to a **private** file via email?

Comment: Because clients are ... well, users. And users can easily send a link to a document to anybody (you do send links in emails, right?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Federico Dipuma. I used this way in one of my projects. I am here to share my code.

Code of generate SAS URL.

```
public string GetBlobSasUri(string containerName, string blobName, string connectionstring)
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionstring);
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

    //Set the expiry time and permissions for the blob.
    //In this case no start time is specified, so the shared access signature becomes valid immediately.
    SharedAccessBlobPolicy sasConstraints = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy();
    sasConstraints.SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10);
    sasConstraints.Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read;

    //Generate the shared access signature on the blob, setting the constraints directly on the signature.
    string sasContainerToken = blockBlob.GetSharedAccessSignature(sasConstraints);

    //Return the URI string for the blob, including the SAS token.
    return blockBlob.Uri + sasContainerToken;
}
```

Redirect to the URL in your web application.

```
public ActionResult  FileDownload()
{
    string blobURL = GetBlobSasUri("blob name","container name", "connection string");
    return Redirect(blobURL);
}
```